# How to Refresh PXDBScalar

Tags: acumatica

I have added an unbound field to the ARInvoice DAC and set a PXDBScalar attribute.  The problem I'm having is that the PXDBScalar attribute doesn't seem to update the field value when other fields post back or if I hit the Save button on screen AR301000.  I have to click on the Refresh button on the browser in order to get the field to update.  How can I update the unbound field, that has the PXDBScalar attribute, whenever there is a post back on the page?

Here's what the unbound field looks like:

```
    #region UsrBranchOrg
    [PXInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Branch Org")]
    [PXDefault(0)]
    [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<Branch.organizationID, Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<PX.Objects.AR.ARRegister.branchID>>>))]
    public virtual Int32? UsrBranchOrg { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrBranchOrg : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrBranchOrg> { }
    #endregion
```

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The definition of ARInvoice inherits from ARRegister.

```
public partial class ARInvoice : ARRegister, IInvoice, ICreatePaymentDocument
```

The ARInvoice.BranchID field is defined as:

```
public new abstract class branchID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<branchID> { }

/// <summary>
/// The identifier of the <see cref="Branch">branch</see> to which the document belongs.
/// </summary>
/// <value>
/// Corresponds to the <see cref="Branch.BranchID"/> field.
/// </value>
[Branch(typeof(AccessInfo.branchID), IsDetail = false, TabOrder = 0)]
[PXFormula(typeof(Switch<
    Case<Where<PendingValue<ARInvoice.branchID>, IsPending>, Null,
    Case<Where<ARInvoice.customerLocationID, IsNotNull,
            And<Selector<ARInvoice.customerLocationID, Location.cBranchID>, IsNotNull>>,
        Selector<ARInvoice.customerLocationID, Location.cBranchID>,
    Case<Where<Current2<ARInvoice.branchID>, IsNotNull>,
        Current2<ARInvoice.branchID>>>>,
    Current<AccessInfo.branchID>>))]
public override Int32? BranchID
{
    get
    {
        return this._BranchID;
    }
    set
    {
        this._BranchID = value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

What this means is that the Branch ID is set via formula (and not stored in the database) when you change the customer location on the ARInvoice.  All that said, you are looking up the branch from an ARRegister object instead of the ARInvoice record itself.

Does it work if you simply change the Search to:

```
[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<Branch.organizationID,
    Where<Branch.branchID, Equal<branchID>>>))]
```

In this case, it will pull branchID from the current DAC (ARInvoice).  When you reference other DAC's as you have, often you have to include Current<> or .FromCurrent, depending on whether using BQL or FBQL, respectively.  *<- in all honesty, not 100% sure if "Current" would apply to ARRegister in this case, but I'd still change the reference to point directly to ARInvoice.*

Assuming branchID defaulted properly on ARInvoice, and there is no reason it should not, then referencing it should change the Organization ID selected when you commit a change to CustomerLocationID on the ARInvoice which subsequently changes (via PXForumla) the BranchID on the ARInvoice.